# Centos 6.8 memcached not found

Tags: centos, wordpress, memcached, memcache, php-memcached

Installed latest version of memcached(1.4.28) with these instructions:

`wget http://memcached.googlecode.com/files/memcached-1.4.13.tar.gz
tar -xzf memcached-1.4.13.tar.gz 
cd memcached-1.4.13
./configure
make && make install`

I've got the module in my php.ini. I can not get it to run though. I've tried various startup scripts in /etc/init.d/memcached to no avail.

I've tried manually starting with this
`memcached -d -u memcached -m 1024 127.0.0.1 -p 11211`
and I get command not found. My goal is to use this with multiple wordpress sites hosted on the same server.

Answer (score 1):

> What am I missing?

That `memcached` needs to be in your path.

Comment: I thought this might be a possibility. I'm not sure where it's at though.. As I said I followed the instructions above for install, but if i do 'find -name "memcached"` The only location I see is that install folder.

Comment: Perhaps you need to find from a higher level directory. Perhaps `configure` --help will be useful too.

Comment: Usually custom built software goes under /usr/local somewhere (perhaps /usr/local/bin) unless you specify otherwise. You could run `make install` again and watch the output to see what it did/does. Or look at the Makefiles and see what they say. Did you forget to install as root? Miss errors during the install? Does memcached use a different filename for it's executable? Is there a memcached binary/executable in the build directory?

Comment: Noob moment. Sorry guys, I appreciate your help.  In the midst of troubleshooting, I had compiled "libmemcached" which appears to be outdated not "memcached" - it appears to be running now!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my problem. In the midst of troubleshooting, I had compiled "libmemcached" which appears to be outdated not "memcached" - it appears to be running now!